# How to determine Controller Name and method given a URL in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, controller

Is there a way to obtain the Spring Controller Name and method given a URL in Spring Boot?

Edit : Some more details. I want to add the Spring controller name and method to the SLF4J MDC from a Servlet Filter so I have access to the HttpRequest object. So I pretty much need the same logic that Spring uses to map the HtttRequest to the handler. As I'm typing this it occurred to me that I could run the code in a debugger to get to the logic used by Spring and replicate it. I'll post an update when I get to it

Answer (score 0):

A URL alone isn’t sufficient to perform request mapping. For example, a `@GetMapping` will only match a `GET` request and the method of the request (`GET`, `POST`, etc) can’t be determined from the URL. Mapping can also depend on headers in the request. For example, the content types that a controller method produces has to match one of those listed in the `Accept` header of the request.

If you had a complete request, you could determine what will handle it. Assuming that you are using Spring MVC, you could call `getHandlerMappings()` on your application’s `DispatcherServlet`. Then call `getMapping(HttpServletRequest)` on each handler mapping in turn until you get a non-null result. The handler (returned by `getHandler()`) is what would be used to handle the request.